What underlying type is a handle, specifically a HWND window handle?
I have this code that gets a handle to the active window and sets the window to stay on top of other windows or resets it to normal.
HWND hand = GetActiveWindow();

if (!hand)
{
    return FALSE;
}
 
SetWindowPos(hand, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
// OR
SetWindowPos(hand, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

Rather than using the C++ code, I need to call these functions from another language, specifically LabVIEW. In LabVIEW I call the GetActiveWindow() function in User32.dll. I need to tell LabVIEW what the types of input and return parameters are but LabVIEW has no notion of a "HWND" type. The only allowed types are listed in drop-down menus as:
Void
Numeric
    Signed 8-bit Integer
    Signed 16-bit Integer
    Signed 32-bit Integer
    Signed 64-bit Integer
    Signed Pointer-sized Integer
    Unsigned 8-bit Integer
    Unsigned 16-bit Integer
    Unsigned 32-bit Integer
    Unsigned 64-bit Integer
    Unsigned Pointer-sized Integer
    4-byte Single
    8-byte Double
String
    C String Pointer
    Pascal String Pointer

Which is the correct type and what is the process for determining it including broader contexts?
I am using the 32-bit version of LabVIEW. There is a 64-bit version. If that matters I can conditionally compile different code.
On one hand I feel like the answer is a Pointer-sized Integer and signed or unsigned doesn't matter even if I am inconsistent between function calls. But a handle is not exactly the same as a pointer so on the other hand the answer could be a signed or unsigned 32-bit integer. If I switch to a 64-bit LabVIEW version, do I then need to call a 64-bit version of the DLL and switch to a 64-bit integer?

If this involves C++ and LabVIEW, why have you tagged it C?

According to this a HWND is of type void* (after you do some looking around)

I was only able to apply 5 tags and thought C was more relevant since there is no C++ involved between LabVIEW and the DLL. I guess I thought the DLL is made with C. But I don't understand all the boundaries between technologies perfectly. I changed the C tag to C++. Thank you.

In the future, you can just print sizeof(hand) to figure out how many bytes it has, then treat it as an integer of that size.  I'd make it unsigned but that doesn't matter much.

But what is on the other side of the void* is an implementation detail you'll have a fair amount of difficulty determining. That's the beauty (and horror) of a void *: It is the ultimate in abstraction. You have no clue what is on the other side and if you need to know, and fortunately you don't seem to here, you're doing something wrong or the designer of the interface did something very, very wrong. Pray for the former as you can do something about your mistakes. All you can do with a bad interface is get a different library.

TLDR: Declare it as a void* within LabView.
Formally, you can see in the Windows SDK that's it's declared like this:
DECLARE_HANDLE            (HWND);

And the DECLARE_HANDLE macro expands to this:
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name

So DECLARE_HANDLE(HWND) formally expands to this:
struct HWND__{
    int unused;
}; 
typedef struct HWND__ *HWND;

So an HWND is just a pointer to a dummy struct. But what it really "points" to is something different entirely meant only for Windows internals to consume. It's really just an integer key to a hash table that contains the actual internals.  But you don't need to know that for interop with labview.
As far as interop with other programming languages, you should treat HWNDs as a void*.  LabView just needs to know it's an opaque pointer to generate the correct size for the parameter calls and return values across the stack.

LabVIEW does not have a "void*" type and I still struggle with C/C++ pointer syntax. The only types LabVIEW has are listed in my original question (updated with non-numeric types). Does it make since that void* corresponds to Pointer-sized Integer and signed/unsigned doesn't really matter? Where the bitness of the application determines the size of the pointer.

@Jonathan The LabVIEW equivalent is a "Signed Pointer-sized Integer".

FWIW this is true only if STRICT is defined, otherwise a HWND is just typedef'd as void*.
